# Пагинация на jQuery и AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Добрый день!

Такая задача: есть страница на ней 5 вкладок, на каждой из вкладок X (пусть 1000) элементов (фото, описания и т.д.) и есть пагинатор (на PHP и MySQL ... LIMIT (номер страницы-1)*количество элементов, количество элементов). Если делать на AJAX, то необходимо при первом заходе получить сразу 5000 элементов? Это может замедлить загрузку, т.к. SQL-запросы тоже занимают время. Или нет необходимости загружать всё сразу?

И как вообще пагинацию можно сделать на AJAX, если выборка из базы идёт посредством PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Какая разница, как вы обращаетесь к базе? При первом заходе на страницу загружаете только первую вкладку, а остальные подгружаете на ходу через аякс. Здесь под подгрузкой подразумевается "фоновый" запрос к серверу, результатом которого должна стать необходимая вкладка. На запрос вешаете свой обработчик и всё.

Пагинация на Ajax - это всего-то кнопочки, по нажатию на которые происходит ajax-запрос к серверу, который обрабатывается средствами php (т.е. пишете сами). Не знаю, как уж проще написать...

Comment: Мне кажется, что стоит после загрузки текущей вкладки начать загружать следующую. Тогда сообщение "Идет загрузка, подождите..." для пользователя  будет появляться реже. Но это мое имхо, и разумеется все зависит от того как часто пользователь посмотрев текущую вкладку тыкает по следующей.

Comment: Это уже вопрос оптимизации... Да и какова она - следующая? Как вариант уменьшать количество контента на вкладке, что бы была быстрая подгрузка, но в разумных пределах - а то юзеры заманаются счёлкать) Но мне кажется, мы отклоняемся от темы ;) Автор, ау! :)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете JQuery, то я думаю, что стоит использовать специальный плагин. Ссылка на github: [jQuery Pagination Plugin](https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination#readme). Ссылка на сайт с плагинами: [Pagination](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination).

Comment: Имхо проще написать самому, будет пара-тройка аякс-запросов и немного логики по манипуляции объектами DOM. Но это моё имхо.

Comment: @metazet врятли проще, как правило jquery-плагины имеют весьма минималестический интерфейс для взаимодействия, так что его явно проще изучить чем написать с нуля. Разумеется это относится к тому плагину который полностью удовлетворяет потребностям, ибо изменять близкий по функционалу до требуемого уровня может вылиться в 7 кругов ада.

Comment: @GLAGOLA, как верно Вы подметили про 7 кругов ада :) Ведь случаи, когда такие хитрые плагины подходят целиком и полностью - редки... Это из личного опыта :)

Comment: @metazet, Честно говоря, даже если плагин не подошел, то я бы не стал реализовывать все на чистом JS+DOM, а скорее бы написал свой плагин для jQuery, который бы удовлетворял моим потребностям.

Comment: @GLAGOLA, полностью с Вами согласен :)